# React Navigation set individual tab colors

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Can't seem to figure out how to change the "activeTintColor" for individual tabs on my TabNavigator

basic setup is here, where and what do I insert to set the activeTintColor for each tab instead of all 3

```
const MainApp = TabNavigator({
  Tab1: { screen: Screen1, 
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Screen 1'}
  },
  Tab2: { screen: Screen2, 
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Screen 2'}
  },
  Tab3: { screen: Screen3, 
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Screen 3'}
  }
},{
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarOptions: {
    //activeTintColor: "this sets it for all 3"
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to implement tabBarIcon in each screen's navigationOptions with different color.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I'll put this here in case anyone else struggles

```
import { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom } from "react-navigation";
import * as Colors from '../assets/Colors';
//My color file

const MainApp = TabNavigator(
  {
    Tab1: { screen: Tab1, navigationOptions: { title: 'Title'}},
    Tab2: { screen: Tab2, navigationOptions: { title: 'Title'}},
    Tab3: { screen: Tab3, navigationOptions: { title: 'Title'}},
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        let color; //init color variable
        switch (routeName) {
          case 'Tab1':
            color = Colors.Tab1; //set color variable here
            iconName = Platform.OS === 'ios'
              ? //IOS ICON
              : //ANDROID ICON;
            break;
          case 'Tab2':
            color = Colors.Tab2; //set color variable here
            iconName = Platform.OS === 'ios'
              ? //IOS ICON
              : //ANDROID ICON;
            break;
          case 'Tab3':
            color = Colors.Tab3; //set color variable here
            iconName = Platform.OS === 'ios'
              ? //IOS ICON
              : //ANDROID ICON;
        }
        return (
          <Ionicons
            name={iconName}
            size={35}
            style={{ //style stuff }}
            color={focused ? color : Colors.tabIconDefault}
          />
        );
      },
    }),
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    lazy: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true, //this is default false on Android
      showLabel: false,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.DarkUI,
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        opacity: 0
      }
    },
  }
);
```